# Is the Java Integer cache a realization of the object pool pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

One of the best-known examples of a full-fledged object pool is the JDBC connection pool. Main reasons:

- objects in the pool are expensive to create and relate with external resources
- each object in the pool is served to at most one client a time
- objects in the pool need to be brought back to a clean state before being served again to a new client

With the above in mind, can the Java Integer cache be regarded as a object pool realization? Here is why I doubt it:

- objects in the pool can be used by more than one client a time due to their immutability
- immutability also prevents pool objects from reaching a stale state
- there's no notion of a "free" object, ready to be allocated to a client

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is really the **[flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)** pattern which is a specialized sort of object pool, where objects get shared to save memory.

Answer (score -2):

The problem with a Java Integer cache is that the VM is optimized for boxing/unboxing.  The lookup mechanism for a "cached" Java Integer is going to be more expensive than just creating the object.

```
building cache
test length 500,000,000
cached duration: 12001.345937
boxed duration: 12108.983383
```

In many scenarios the lookup using many threads is going to cause lots of cache misses across different cores and have more of a performance hit.

```
System.out.println("building cache");

Integer[] cache = new Integer[50000];

for( int i = 0; i < cache.length; i ++)
{
    cache[i] = new Integer(i);
}

int c = 500 * 1000000;
int t = 0;

System.out.println("test length " + c );

NanoStopWatch watch = new NanoStopWatch();

watch.start();

while( t < c)
{
    Integer p = cache[ (int)  (Math.random() * 5000) ];

    t++;
}

watch.stop();

System.out.println("cached duration: " + watch.duration() );

t = 0;

watch.start();

while( t < c)
{
    Integer p =  (Integer) (int) (Math.random() * 5000);

    t++;
}

watch.stop();

System.out.println("boxed duration: " + watch.duration() );
```

Comment: Sounds possible, but do you have timings to support this?

Comment: edited answer..

Comment: That is a *terrible* benchmark. Even ignoring that, simply reversing the order of the tests changes the results of the benchmark.

Comment: numbers are the same every time within .01% forwards and backwards - maybe if you could explain a better way to test this?

Comment: Are you saying that you get the same results when you swap the order? When I run the benchmark (had to use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `NanoStopWatch`), the first one to go always takes between 0.1-0.3 seconds longer to run, whether it is cached or boxed.

Comment: I'm not a benchmark master, but the thing that stands out to me the most is that those loops look like they *should* be optimized away quite quickly by the JITC (not sure why they aren't though...). I'm somewhat suspicious of the `Math.random()` calls, too. A super rough replacement of the `Math.random()` calls with a pre-generated array of random `int`s actually show a significant advantage for the cache method; I admit though that the altered benchmark is likely still significantly flawed.

Comment: Math.random() should be what is totally preventing any VM optimization.  I did that on purpose.  Otherwise you get this kind of result: http://pastebin.com/vTgpX4Ag java code: http://pastebin.com/HPmG6bBT

Comment: I'm confused.  The boxed is very slightly slower by your timings, so no benefit there, right?  (It is surprising close, nice to know)  And we know that boxing will lead to a lot more garbage collection and memory churning.  So your benchmark shows that caches are still of some benefit.

Comment: Its more complicate than just boxing vs. array lookups.  If you are going to do fast iterations then do lookups but if you are doing intense tasks across cpus then boxing may be a better option.  Always avoid boxing when you can.

Comment: I see... idk, this kind of benchmark sets off alarm bells for me, and now that you explained things I'm not sure why. I'd love to try this in a benchmarking framework like JMH if I knew how...

Comment: Writing benchmark code for the JVM is like trying to analyze silly putty.  You can look at the byte code but down to the metal only a few people know how HotSpot will react in every situation.